# ¿Como puedo sumar datos que dependen de otros generales?

Tags: java, bucle-for

la pregunta se plantea de la siguiente manera.

Un banco posee un gran número de sucursales distribuidas en diversas zonas. Tiene un lote de registros con los siguiente datos:

- Código de zona (1 a 10)
- Código de sucursal (1 a 35)
- Nombre del cliente (20 caracteres)
- Saldo del cliente

El lote se ingresa agrupado por zona y dentro de zona por sucursal. El fin se indica con un registro con código de zona igual a cero.
Se desea obtener un listado con los saldos de los clientes totalizados por sucursal, por zona y el total general, con el siguiente formato:

Sucursal xx:        Saldo acumulado de todos los clientes: xxxxxxxxxx
Sucursal xx:        Saldo acumulado de todos los clientes: xxxxxxxxxx

```
                Total Zona xx:    xxxxxxxx
```

Total General:     xxxxxxxx

El codigo que puse para sumar el total en las zonas es el siguiente:

```
 public static void zona() {
    double saldo = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ListaBanco.size(); j++) {
            if (ListaBanco.get(j).getCodigo() == i) {
                saldo += ListaBanco.get(j).getSaldo();
            }
        }
        if (saldo != 0) {
            System.out.println("TOTAL ZONA " + (i) + ": " + saldo);
        }
        saldo = 0;
    }
}
```

Cual seria el correcto para calcular cada sucursal dependiendo de la zona en la que se encuentre independientemente ?.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Deberiamos saber como es tu objeto ListaBanco, para saber bien que tiene. Igual mas alla de eso, supongo que necesitaras otro for para recorrer las sucursales. aparte de eso, no entiendo nada de tu codigo.